# How do i handle selection change with collection view and navigate to the item detail page with prism

Tags: xamarin, mvvm

Im Trying to select a an item in collection view and i want to view the item details from that page. please see my code below.

View

```
 <CollectionView  x:Name="CvCategories"
                    HeightRequest="130"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectionChanged="CvCategories_SelectionChanged">
  <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
```

Code Behind

```
 private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var currentSelection = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Category;
            if (currentSelection == null) return;
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CategoryListPage(currentSelection.id, currentSelection.name));
       
            ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
        }
```

Comment: What is your question?  Does your code work?  If not, what is wrong with it?  Does it throw an exception or cause a compiler error?

Comment: I want to call the prism navigation and pass the id and the name of the item in the next page.